# Implement web notifications to meteor js app

Tags: meteor, notifications

Hello I'm trying to learn Meteor Js and i started building a simple task manager app.
I want to add a notification (using the notifications api), when a user adds a task from an input. My problem is that I cant find a way to send the notifications between users from the server side.
What i have so far :

```
   Template.listPage.events({

      'submit #newItem':function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

//variables to insert here here. i dont post for space issues.
// Call server method for insert into db 

Meteor.call('addItem',item,d,user,datestring,currentList,listName,assign);

// This is what i m trying to implement   
        var items = todos.find({name:item}).observe({
         added:function() {
            var n = new Notification("hello new task added")
          }

        })


      },
```

The above works as : 
The notification is shown only to the user that adds the task (not really useful). 
How can I use this in server side, In order to:
**Show the notification to all users using the app?** Is this possible or I have to use a push notification package?
PS: I ask for users permition to receive notifications on Meteor.startup.

Comment: Which notifications package are you using?

Comment: Try https://atmospherejs.com/gunjansoni/html5-api package. It has Desktop Web notifications and much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specify the observe within the click event. Therefore, only users who have triggered the event (i.e. clicked the button) will get the notification.

In order to activate the observer for everyone do the following:

```
Template.listPage.rendered = function(){
    todos.find().observe({
        added: function() {
            ... do whatever you want to do here
        }
    })
 };
```

Comment: thanks for the input.This works as intended, but has one flaw, it fires on page load for every item in my collection.How can I run it only when a new item is added? My version : `Template.main.rendered = function(){
      todos.find().observeChanges({
        added: function(id,doc) {
          //variables here

        if(agent){
          var options = {body:"User : "+user+"\nTask : "+name+"\nProject : "+project+"\nAssign : "+assign,icon:"/launch-icon.png"}
           var n = new Notification("New Task",options);
         }

          
        },

     
    })
           
 };`

Answer (score 0):

To add notifications, you could use a package such as `yogiben:notifications`:
https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/notifications

(There might be better packages for this nowadays. Search on Atmosphere.)

Alternatively, you can roll your own solution. The basic idea would be add create a collection called `Notifications`. Then add notifications whenever you feel like it and publish the relevant notifications to whichever user(s) you'd like.

The code in your question will also work as long as you're publishing the relevant `todos` to different users.